# ABPersonViewController does not support subclassing in iOS 7.0 and later

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, addressbookui

`is there any best way to listout Property of Contact in detail?`
 `like it is working in IOS 6.1 and earlier Version.`

---

```
//
//  ABPersonViewController.h
//  AddressBookUI
//
//  Copyright (c) 2010 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIViewController.h>
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>

@interface ABPersonViewController : UIViewController <UIViewControllerRestoration>

// ABPersonViewController does not support subclassing in iOS 7.0 and later. A nil instance will be returned.
```

Comment: Not sure what the subclassing restriction is supposed to achieve/prevent but anything that you could achieve by subclassing you could also achieve through other, if perhaps hackier, means like method swizzling or proxying, etc. That said, it's not clear what you're asking here.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution :please see [source](https://github.com/jetanikalpesh/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree/master/C18-Address%20Book/04b-Property%20Picker)

there is some deprecated functions but we can resolve it,
by replace Below function in "ABContactsHelper" Class

```
+ (ABAddressBookRef) addressBook
{
#ifdef __IPHONE_6_0
    return ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
#else
    return ABAddressBookCreate();
#endif
}
```

Use it where "ABAddressBookCreate()" is Called.
Like

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = [ABContactsHelper addressBook];
```

Comment: That code is using deprecated API for accessing the address book. It will require significant updating.